# depict beyond character range

Tags: java

When I run the following statement,

```
    System.out.println("Character is "+(char)65536); //equivalent to 0x10000
```

I get the output as

```
Character is
```

How can it be depicted?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class provides the following methods

```
Character.highSurrogate(codePoint);
Character.lowSurrogate(codePoint);
```

for retrieving the surrogates, given a code point.

Once you have those, you can write them to a `ByteBuffer` and get the corresponding `byte[]` and use it to create a new `String` with UTF-16 encoding.

```
//  byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) 0xD8, 0x34, (byte) 0xDD, 0x1E };
String text = ""; // new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
int codePoint = text.codePointAt(0);

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
buf.putChar(Character.highSurrogate(codePoint));
buf.putChar(Character.lowSurrogate(codePoint));
byte[] data = buf.array();

// recreated
String rep = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

Comment: @NonymousNT Oops, sorry, I misunderstood what you were looking for. Does my edit clarify things?

Answer (score 0):

The method [`Character.toChars(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29) will give you the UTF-16 series of code units corresponding to that code point.

So, for your example:

```
System.out.println("Character is " + new String(Character.toChars(65536))); //equivalent to U+10000
```

will print a U+10000 ('LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A'), assuming you have that font.

Answer (score 0):

Java was designed to hold text in Unicode, so all scripts (say Cyrillic, Arabic, Greek) of all languages could be combined.

Unicode symbols are called *code points* and are numbers needing 3 bytes. U+10000 would be the code point you mentioned. It is LINEAR B SYLLABLE B008 A.

Code points are stored in `int` in java. `String` holds an array of `char` where a char is a 2 byte UTF-16BE encoded value. As Unicode goes into the 3 byte range, sometimes 2 chars are needed to represent one code point. The UTF-16 encoding ensures that ASCII characters like `/` are not erroneously found in the bytes.

Furthermore java stores string literals, class and method names as UTF-8 in .class files.
UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding.

- UTF-8 has 7-bits ASCII code points as subset, the byte sequence (byte)0x63 is indeed the codepoint U+0063 aka 'c'.
- UTF-16 has a large part of Unicode as subset: the char `\u10000` indeed is code point U+10000.

Hence using `char` values is always a partial solution. One better uses code points.

The answer:

System.out uses the default platform encoding, and will not be able to represent all Unicode. Also the console font must be able to depict the code point. When conversion is not possible mostly `?` or a `<?>` placeholder will be shown.

The solution is to write to a file, in UTF-8. And open the file in UTF-8, say with Notepad++, and install a huge Unicode font.